# How to edit and delete users from database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin

I don't know how to do a edit and delete function in codeigniter.. I really need it for the admin side of my system.. I really need help.. I want to delete the id in my table named user_acc and edit the whole column

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mod_admin extends CI_Model{
 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 

    public function user_acc(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_acc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }


    public function delete()
    {
        $this->db->where('id');
        $this->db->delete();
    }



}
```

Admin:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {


      public function __construct()

    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
       $this->load->Model('Mod_admin');

    }

public function manageuser(){
    $this->load->view('template/adminhead');
    $data['user_acc'] = $this->Mod_admin->user_acc();
    $this->load->view('manageuser', $data);
}


public function delete_product() {
    $this->Mod_admin->delete();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p>Product were successfully deleted!</p>');
    redirect('manageuser');
}



}
```

View:

```
<html>

<title>Manage User</title>
<body>

<style>
  .shit{
    border: 1px solid;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }

   .shit td{
    border: 1px solid;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 7px;
  }

  .shit td tr{
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .shit td th{
    border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>
  <div id="container">
  <table class="shit">
        <tr>
            <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Firstname</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Lastname</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Password</strong></th>
            <th><strong>E-mail</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Contact</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
        </tr>

    <?php


                foreach($user_acc as $row){

                echo 

                      '<tr> 

                          <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->firstname.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->lastname.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->username.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->password.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
                          <td>'.$row->contact.'</td>
                          <td>'.'<a href="#">'.'Edit</a>'.'</td>
                          <td>'.'<a href="#">'.'Delete</a>'.'</td> 
                      </tr>';



                }
            ?>
</table>
</div>



</body>
</html>]
```

[How View looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf3iB.jpg)
Please help me to edit and delete users thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating

**In controller**:

```
$result = array( 'column1'=>$val1,'column2'=>$val2,'column3'=>$val3);
$this->model_name->updateEvent( $id , $result );
```

**In model:**

```
public function updateEvent($id, $result){
     $this->db->where('db_table_column', $id);
     $this->db->update('table_name', $result);
}
```

For deleting

**In controller:**

```
$this->model_name->deleteEvent( $id );
```

**In model:**

```
public function deleteEvent( $id )
{
    $this->db->where('db_table_column', $id);
    $this->db->delete('table_name');
}
```

Comment: how can I put it in view?

Comment: Why you want to put it on view though can put on `view` page? You are using `MVC` pattern. From `view` page `submit` your `form/action` to `controller action`. From `controller` the `model function` is called.

Comment: I mean in button.. what should I put here  <td>'.'<a href="#">'.'Edit</a>'.'</td> am I going to use ahref or onclick?

Comment: `<a href="<?=base_url?>index.php/controller/action?param=<?=$var?>">Click</a>`